# Special Character Question Mark Show (Laravel Project)

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem with the special character (question mark)  was shown to my content
All the suggestions I already use but still the question mark is showing.

- `Blade::setEchoFormat('e(utf8_encode(%s))');`
- `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">`
- `<meta charset="utf-8">`

**Sample text have question mark sign**

```
     $footersign = "©";

     <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">{!! $footersign !!} <?php echo date("Y"); ?>
             Hi-Flyer Food. Designed by Solutions Experts and Enablers, Inc.
     </div>
```

Sample Image:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]

Comment: why don't you try html entity name or number  for that  ? e.g.  $footersign = "&copy;"; or $footersign = "&#169;";  instead of  $footersign = "©";

Comment: i put the © in my blade, it show correct, are you sure set <meta charset="utf-8"> , and your file is encoded UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: yes it works. but with the sign text it won't work. sample i have this text À Propos de nous the output is ?Propos de nous

Comment: no problem for me here, i can see  `À Propos de nous`, your all file, *.php must save as UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: hmmm in php.ini are you turned on `zend.multibyte = ` or `zend.script_encoding =`

Comment: no no no, first remove the `Blade::setEchoFormat('e(utf8_encode(%s))');` , i saw you set the meta to UTF-8 `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` , but the `php file is encoded to UTF-8 without BOM` ???

Comment: open the php file in your editor, check is it encoded UTF-8 without BOM

Answer (score 1):

please change

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

to

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

because  utf-8 can represent all characters hving iso-8859-1 also, try html entity name or number like

```
$footersign = "&copy;"; or $footersign = "&#169;";
```

instead of

```
$footersign = "©";
```

Comment: hi,  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> is not working to me. Is it possible to use the actual letter not the raw html?

Comment: please check encoding of your file.. is it ASCII Or anyother? change it to utf-8 and save file... and try reopening in browser .. this should help you

Comment: no.. that code is ok.... what are you using for editing file ? notepad++ or any other ??

Answer (score 0):

check your php file is encoded UTF-8 without BOM

[image]

Comment: in the database column, are you use CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE  `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` <- depends on what you need

Comment: hi kenken. I solved the problem. the solution is the encode in my FTP is set to ASCI (Latin) so everytime the system upload it. the text converted to ASCI not UTF-8. the problem is in the Application. thanks advance